# SSRS - Trying to find all User Reports tied to a Batch File / Subscriptions

Tags: reporting-services

I have tried various queries I have found to try and accomplish this and none of them seem to list all the batch file/subscription instances tied to a user report in SSRS.  If there is already a batch file out there tied to a user report, that's what I want to use versus creating a new batch file.  I have tried going through the tables in the ReportServer database and looking for records to link to try and find this information, but I have been unsuccessful. Sorry if this is a simplistic question, but I have spent a few days trying to figure this out.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get at all subscriptions on your report server by running the following query:

You can alter this to suit your needs

```
use [ReportServer]

SELECT 
R.Name
, L.TimeDataRetrieval
,L.TimeProcessing
,L.TimeRendering 
, L.TimeDataRetrieval+L.TimeProcessing+L.TimeRendering AS TotalTime
,L.Format
,L.[Parameters]
,L.username
,L.TimeStart 
,L.TimeEnd
,l.ReportID
,DATEDIFF(SECOND,L.timestart,L.timeend) time_seconds
,r.Path

FROM dbo.ExecutionLog L  

INNER JOIN dbo.Catalog R  
    ON L.ReportID = R.ItemID 
    
 
WHERE 
R.Name like  'name of your report'
```

Comment: I have been able to pull up the lists of Batch Files and Subscriptions, the missing piece is that if a Batch File / Subscription is calling another report, I want to know that report name.  So if Batch File / Subscription "Inactive" is looking at rpt.InactiveList from User Report I want to know that information.  I tried looking at all the multicharacter ids trying to find a match in another table but couldn't find it.